# Questions about sentencepiece tokenizer

Tags: nlp, tokenization

The SentencePiece original paper [manuscript](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.06226.pdf) is as vague as it can get about the implementation of the algorithm. The paper describes the problems with a BPE or Unigram tokenizer and then claims that SentencePiece solves them and then directly jumps into the usage details of the SentencePiece library

The problem with the BPE and Unigram Tokenizers, as described in the paper:

1. They require a pre-tokenizer and many languages are vague about the separation (or even definition) of words (like Japanese etc)
2. They are not lossless. Pre-tokenization loses information like multiple whitespaces etc

SentencePiece claims to solve these. It is also mentioned that SentencePiece can be used in two modes - Unigram and BPE. Also, the data to be fed to the SentencePiece library is supposed to be in the format of one sentence per line in the file

Questions:

1. How are the algorithms Unigram and BPE used with the SentencePiece such that a pre-tokenizer is not needed
2. What is this sentence that should be present per line of the text file? If I have a corpus of documents how do I create the input for the SentencePiece? Do I separate the documents by the period symbol (.) and place each element in a line in the file to be fed to SentencePiece? That sounds weird but okay
3. Is SentencePiece using this "Sentence" as a single pre-tokenized unit?

Comment: did you figure this out? especially number 2